Kalman Filters: Reject one measurement but not the other
I have Kalman Filter that has two inputs from identical magnetic sensors. The goal is to get the direction that the dome that the sensors are attached to is pointing. The issue is that there are motors placed around the base of the dome that interfere with the sensors. this can be mitigated by using a single sensor high up, but I think it would be better to have two sensors anyways as the interference is quite strong.
the sensors are spaced so that when one has interference the other is unaffected.
I have the filter set up so that it operates on the independently calculated angle from each sensor. I don't feel the need to include the x and y axis independently (although writing this I may experiment with that, just to see how the results are). I want to reject outliers from one of the sensors but not the other
what I have seen others do is to skip the entire update step, but I don't think I can do that because I want to update with the other measurement that isn't bogus
I think that an adaptive filter is probably the best route forward, but would Like to see if there are other options

Kalman filters are adaptive filters and are designed for this case. You can add information about the reliability of each sensor by modifying the sensor covariance matrix between updates. From the sensor data, you will need to estimate the uncertainty of the sensor (e.g., calculating an SNR).

See my answer to this question, here the reason for a different measurement are due to different sample rates, but the same idea also holds for rejecting a sensor due to measurement interference. You do also need to update the covariance used for the measurement noise.

If you know which sensor(s) have good outputs ahead of time, it's easy-peasy.  Just use three system models: one that just reads sensor 1, one that reads just sensor 2, and one (for when both sensors are good) that reads both.
Then update the Kalman filter at each step with the model that corresponds to your collection of good sensors.  The dynamics ($F$ and $G$ matrices) never change, just the measurement matrix ($H$ matrix).
If you don't know which sensor is good, then you could predict the measurement vector from the current state, compare it to your two sensors, and throw out the one that matches the worst.  This will present you with some challenges in initializing the filter (how do you know if the sensor or the state estimate is wrong?), but assuming it'll initialize, it should be good afterwards.
